# How to force array type?

Tags: powershell

When I run `Get-ChildItem` in a directory with only one file, I get a single `DirectoryInfo` object:

```
PS H:\> (ls).GetType().Name
DirectoryInfo
```

As soon as I add a second file, the output becomes an array:

```
PS H:\> (ls).GetType().Name
Object[]
```

How should I deal with this dichotomy in a function? Ideally, I'd like to force it to return an `Array` even when there's only one element, preferably without having to put in conditional logic based on the result of `GetType()` or `Length` or whatever.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use array operator `@()`: `$Array=@(ls)`. That operator guaranteed that you will have an array even if pipeline return zero or one object.

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on PetSerAl's answer, you could also cast the type you need more explicitly:

- `[array](ls)` will get you a `System.Array` object with a single member, so you could use this in a place where you want to avoid creating a new variable but need a specific type
- You can also specify arrays that contain only specific types by casting: `[int[]]$integersOnly = 1,2,3` will give you a `System.Array` object that can only hold objects of type `[int]`
- Keep in mind you can use .Net classes - what if you want an array you can modify easily? `[System.Collections.ArrayList](ls)` does that, enjoy using the `Remove()` method

A few other hints, while I'm at it:

- Want to see what you can do with an object of a specific type?  Pipe it to `Get-Member`, the single most useful command I can think of; it'll show you everything you can do with the object
- Curious about a class and what it can do, or looking for details like the different constructors that are available?  Just enter `[<class_name_here>]` and if the assembly is loaded it'll show you everything you want to know